# How can catch event after template is rendered at EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I have an application that uses [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and [Ember JS](http://emberjs.com/) I attempt to search DOM an element by selector, but it retrieves `null` It seems I do it early than template was rendered. Please, help me resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@GJK answer is correct, I just want to provide a working example: http://jsbin.com/enijad/3/edit

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 150,
      itemSelector: '.item'
    });
  }
});
```

The `didInsertElement` function will be called when the view was inserted into the DOM, so it will be safe to initialize additionally libraries.

Also worth mentioning is that if you need some clearing up after the view was removed from the DOM you would do this in didInsertElement's counterpart hook willDestroyElement.

Example:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    // do initialization here
  },
  willDestroyElement: function() {
    // and here you can remove stuff safely
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for examples and wide anwers

Comment: Thanks for the example. I would have provided one, but I knew the syntax would be wrong, and I didn't have access to my codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Create a corresponding View for your Route and Template, and then override the `didInsertElement` method.

Comment: Annoying that you have to do this. This router template thing should really just be a component and have didInsertElement etc

Comment: Well the idea of Ember controlling the DOM for you is that it wants you to do as little manual DOM manipulation as possible. Sometimes it's necessary due to third-party plugins, but 99% of the time `didInsertElement()` is an anti-pattern.